# Need parse dd.MM.yyyy to DateTime using TryParse

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I need to parse string to DateTime. The string is always in the following format

"10.10.2010" That means dd.MM.yyyy, separated with dots.

I want to use DateTime.TryParse or any other method. Please suggest.

UPDATE

Updated the question. I am just looking for the right method to achieve the goal.
Not manual parsing

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`TryParse` doesn't let you specify the format - but you can use [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx):

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "dd'.'MM'.'yyyy",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None,
                           out date))
{
   // Success
}
else
{
   // Parse failed
}
```

Note that the dot doesn't strictly need to be escaped with the quotes, but personally I like to put any literal text in quotes just to make sure that it won't be changed. It's a personal preference thing though - you could certainly just use "dd.MM.yyyy" if you wanted.

Likewise I've specified the invariant culture which is what I normally do for a fixed custom style - but you could make it use the current culture or a specific other culture if you wanted. When you're using a custom style (rather than a standard style such as "long date") it's less likely to make any difference, admittedly.

Comment: what if i am forced to write tryparse then is there any work arround?

Comment: @Neel: Why would you be forced to use `TryParse`? What other restrictions are there? Do you definitely know the format? Can you specify the culture in the `TryParse` call?

Comment: Actually my project is under maintenance and code is already made in which TryParse is used and we are not allowed to change the core part of coding. but now problem is coming like i am using jquery datepicker and it gives me format like MM/dd/yyyy but datetime.tryparse rejects it coz it is expecting dd/MM/yyyy. how is it taking by default or it is taking system's cuture i guess ? @JonSkeet

Comment: @Neel: You should push back on not being allowed to change the core code. You basically have a bug - how would you expect to be able to fix it without changing code? What *are* you allowed to change?

Comment: 12.01.2016 for example is not parsed with this approach. I'm confused

Comment: @Vlado: It works fine for me - I've just tried it (with *exactly* this code). I suggest you ask a new question with a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, and referring to this question as context.

Comment: Yes, exactly this code. Code is fine but my date had whitespace at the end :) .It was very hard to see it. Works fine now.

Comment: When the month or day contain a value with only one digit the parse fails. Is there a way to overcome it other than padding the date string passed with leading zero?

Comment: @LEyahoo: Yes, you'd use a pattern with `d` and `M` instead of `dd` and `MM`. (The way this question was written makes me think it was about values that *are* already zero-padded.)

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) method:

```
DateTime parsed;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(yourString, "dd'.'MM'.'yyyy",
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsed))
{
    // success
}
```

Comment: `null` isn't a valid `DateTimeStyles` value.

Answer (score 5):

Brazil codec

```
public static bool IsDateTime(string txtDate)
{
   DateTime tempDate;

   return DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDate,"dd/MM/yyyy",
                                 new CultureInfo("pt-BR"),
                                 DateTimeStyles.None, out tempDate);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `ParseExact` instead?

```
var theDate = DateTime.ParseExact("dd.MM.yyyy", yourDateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @Dror, if you read the question you will see this: "The string is always in the following format", which would mean that the OP could easily use ParseExact. And he could use a try catch block around it if necessary.

Comment: ParseExact is ok, but it takes at least three parameters

Comment: He did also say "I want to use DateTime.TryParse" - the closest would be TryParseExact. removed down-vote

Answer (score 2):

use [DateTime.TryParseExact(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

try "ddMMyyy", without "- / ."

Answer (score 0):

I have found that jquery datepicker will add non-printable characters in the string. So, when you try to convert to another format, it will throw an invalid date error every time. In my case, I was just trying to convert it back to a time stamp from whatever culture the user was in at the time. It's a somewhat hacky approach, but it worked for me.

```
    static public string ToDigitsOnly(string input)
    {
        Regex digitsOnly = new Regex(@"[^\d]");
        return digitsOnly.Replace(input, "");
    }

    static private DateTime ConvertDateTimeToDate(string dateTimeString, String langCulture)
    {

        System.DateTime result;

        string[] dateString = dateTimeString.Split('/');


        try
        {
            if (langCulture != "en")
            {
                int Year = Convert.ToInt32(ToDigitsOnly(dateString[2]));
                int Month = Convert.ToInt32(ToDigitsOnly(dateString[1]));
                int Day = Convert.ToInt32(ToDigitsOnly(dateString[0]));
                result = new DateTime(Year, Month, Day, 00, 00, 00);
            }
           else
            {
                int Year = Convert.ToInt32(dateString[2]);
                int Month = Convert.ToInt32(dateString[0]);
                int Day = Convert.ToInt32(dateString[1]);
                result = new DateTime(Year, Month, Day, 00, 00, 00);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // last attempt 
            result = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimeString, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
        }

        return result;
    }
```