# ASP.NET MVC Culture change Datetime Format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization, datetime-format

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 with EF project. I'm changing the current thread culture when a user logs in.
Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        CultureInfo objculture = new CultureInfo(Helios.MvcApplication.Lang); //Lang = en-US, ro-RO, fr-FR

        //DateTimeFormatInfo objDTFI = objculture.DateTimeFormat;
        //objDTFI.ShortDatePattern = "dd.MM.YY";
        //objDTFI.DateSeparator = ".";
        //objculture.DateTimeFormat = objDTFI;

        objculture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
        objculture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = objculture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = objculture;   
    }
```

DateTime.cshtml //EditorTemplate for my datetime

```
@model System.DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", Model.HasValue ? Model : DateTime.Today), new { @class = "datefield" })

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".datefield").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, firstDay: 1, changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
    });
});
```

If I use : *String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"* or *String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}"* it works, but if I use *String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}"* it doesn't work.

**Q:** How can I change the datetime format to **"dd.MM.yyyy"** for every culture/language ?

Comment: I'm not clear on what your question is. Are you saying that you want to force the output to a certain format (dd.MM.yyyy) rather than rely on the culture-dependent format?

Comment: Isn't it what are you looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967222/need-parse-dd-mm-yyyy-to-datetime-using-tryparse

Comment: Yes, like I did with the decimal separator

Comment: @Mariusz where do I specify the .TryParseExact method ? (in the DateTime EditorTemplate). This is for converting from string to datetime.

Comment: I missunderstood your question, you want do it in other way. You want to display DateTime object as a string with dd.MM.yyyy format. I am doing it with DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; dt.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"); and it is working well, have you tried it like this?

Comment: Every combination works(MM.dd.yyyy, yyyy.MM.dd,...) only this combination (dd.MM.yyyy) doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but for others needing to change the string format irrespective of the current culture:

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer for this,
and found the answer here

[ASP.NET MVC datetime culture issue when passing value back to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889038/asp-net-mvc-datetime-culture-issue-when-passing-value-back-to-controller)